# jQuery - Trying to make one function to work with multiple, same class, divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i'm trying to make a simple gallery viewer in jquery.

I have something like this in my code:

```
<div class="photoset">
  <img />
  <img />
</div>

<div class="photoset">
  <img />
  <img />
  <img />
</div>
```

And I want, while the first image is showing, the others to be hidden, and if I click on the right half of the image, the next image shows up.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var counter = 0,
    $items = $('.photoset figure'), 
    numItems = $items.length;

    var showCurrent = function () {
        var itemToShow = Math.abs(counter % numItems); 
        $items.removeClass('show');
        $items.eq(itemToShow).addClass('show');
    };

    $("div").click(function (e) {
        var pWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
        var pOffset = $(this).offset();
        var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
        if (pWidth / 2 > x) {
            counter--;
            showCurrent();
        }
        else {
            counter++;
            showCurrent();
        }
    });

});
```

The click function works, but it change all the divs, and I think the counter does not work as I want it to work.

This is the code that generates the gallery:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <br />
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.NomeGaleria)
    <br />
    <div class="photoset">

        @{ var item2 = item.FilePaths;}
        @for (var k = 0; k < Enumerable.Count(item2); k++)
        {
        <br />
        <figure class="@(k == 0 ? "show" : "" ) ">
            <img src="~/images/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem2 => item2[k].FileName)" alt="" height="300" width="500" />
        </figure>
        <br />
        }
    </div>
```

Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm extremely new with jQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

HTML:

```
<div class="photoset">
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-fashion-parade.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals18.jpg" />
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-in-fashion.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals20.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="photoset">
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals26.jpeg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals14.jpg" />
  <img src="http://inspirebee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/animal-fashion.jpg" />
  <img src="https://framboisemood.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/fashion-zoo-animals13.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.fubiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Fashion-Zoo-Animals9.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.photoset > img:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photoset').each(function(){
        $(this).data('counter', 0);
    });

    var showCurrent = function(photoset) {
        $items = photoset.find('img');
        var counter = photoset.data('counter');
        var numItems = $items.length;
        var itemToShow = counter % numItems; 
        $items.hide();
        $items.eq(itemToShow).show();
    };

    $('.photoset').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var photoset = $(this);
        var pWidth = photoset.innerWidth();
        var pOffset = photoset.offset();
        var x = e.pageX - pOffset.left;
        if (pWidth / 2 > x) {
            photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') - 1);
            showCurrent(photoset);
        } else {
            photoset.data('counter', photoset.data('counter') + 1);
            showCurrent(photoset);
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ty0vqk2y/1/

Comment: It works, but it is still targeting all the photoset divs, not the one that i'm particularly clicking.

Comment: Maybe a propagation issue because the click event was set on all divs.
I edited my answer.

Comment: Edited mine as well but still showing the same problem, when I click an image in one photoset, it target all of the others

Comment: Working great now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: There was an error in your showCurrent algorithm: the Math.abs function make a miror instead of a loop between the zero value of counter.

I have also added previous and next arrows in the JSFiddle.